# How to generate Assembly drawing in eagle

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, pcb-fabrication

Hi all for the production purpose the ems partner asked me assembly drawing of my pcb  is there any easy way to create an assembly drawing with part name inside the boxes as in the picture  in eagle?

[image]

Comment: So long as you have made the components in the libraries correctly, then it will be easy to do as Jeroen3 has said. If not, have fun either creating all the names manually, or editing the libraries and updating the board.

Answer (score 2):

Print layer `25 tNames` and layer `21 tPlace`.
Perhaps also `20 Dimension` and `1 Top` with a dim color.